# Optimize getting the first record in a table using an API endpoint with Django REST Framework and/or Django-filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to retrieve the first record in a table using the endpoint below (please suggest if there's a more sensible URL convention).

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/review/?first`

The view I have works, but I'm hoping to refactor it because it smells.

```python
class ReviewViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        first = self.request.query_params.get('first')
        queryset = RecordReview.objects.all()

        if first is not None:
            id_list = queryset.values_list('id')
            first_item = id_list.order_by('id').first()
            first_id = first_item[0]
            queryset = queryset.filter(id=first_id)

        return queryset
```

When I attempted to filter the queryset directly, I got errors like:

`TypeError: object of type 'RecordReview' has no len()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this line :

```py
first_id = first_item[0]
```

This is because `first_item` is already a RecordReview, as it was retrieved using `first()`

You can simplify `get_queryset` as follows though :

```py
class ReviewViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        first = self.request.query_params.get('first')
        queryset = RecordReview.objects.all()

        if first is not None:
            queryset = queryset.order_by('id')[:1]

        return queryset
```

Comment: This is much better. Thank you